# How to move iframe video to center of page?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I tried to move iframe video to center of page but not work , how can i do that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/egjw5p3b/2/

```
<div style="font-size: 1.3em;color:rgb(62, 67, 62);">               
    <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PRJxJdgc4Ng" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 80%;height: 80%;"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try css style margin: 0px auto; on the containing div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code you'd need, if you were going to continue doing this with inline styles:

### HTML

```
<div style="font-size: 1.3em;color:rgb(62, 67, 62); width:500px; margin:0 auto;">
    <div style="position: relative; height: 0; padding-top: 56.25%;">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PRJxJdgc4Ng" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;height:100%;width:100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd highly recommend not doing this with inline styles as you have currently. I would recommend doing this with a stylesheet instead:

### CSS

```
.videoWrapper{
    position:relative;
    padding-top:56:25%;
    max-width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.videoWrapper iframe{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

The `div` cannot be centered properly if it takes up the full width of the container, that's why you need to declare a `width` or `max-width` on it first and then leverage the `margin:0 auto;` declaration to center it horizontally.

If you need this centered vertically, please update your question and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe had the styling set to the absoulute and top:0. If you want to place it dynamically you should not do that.

https://jsfiddle.net/egjw5p3b/3/

> ```
>   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PRJxJdgc4Ng" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="">
>   </iframe>
> ```

Is this what you wanted?